# Create a Filtering Looping Function

Tags: vba, ms-access

Created a Filter Button to search like ID's per an object and the next consecutive Component # that is currently presented on a form. I am filtering from Components 1 to 5. How should I approach this to create a looping function where the cap (5) is fixed or infinite?

```
Private Sub NextComponent_Click()

Me.Refresh

[Forms]![Frm_main_WOSamples]![Frm_sub_Qry_stats_WOSamples].Requery

Dim add As String
Dim MyVar As String
Dim MyCar, myzar As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Tot As Integer
Dim zar, twar, oar, iar, qar As Variant
Dim rep, tep, cep, oep, pep As String

add = "[WOSampleNum] = " & rep
rep = Me.WOSampleNum + 1
tep = Me.WOSampleNum + 2
cep = Me.WOSampleNum + 3
oep = Me.WOSampleNum + 4
pep = Me.WOSampleNum + 5


Dim won As String
Dim ton As String
Dim zon As String

ton = Me.WorkOrderID

zar = DLookup("[WorkOrderID]", "tbl_WOSamples", "[WOSampleNum] =" & rep & " And [WorkOrderID] =" & ton)
oar = DLookup("[WorkOrderID]", "tbl_WOSamples", "[WOSampleNum] =" & tep & " And [WorkOrderID] =" & ton)
twar = DLookup("[WorkOrderID]", "tbl_WOSamples", "[WOSampleNum] =" & cep & " And [WorkOrderID] =" & ton)
iar = DLookup("[WorkOrderID]", "tbl_WOSamples", "[WOSampleNum] =" & oep & " And [WorkOrderID] =" & ton)
qar = DLookup("[WorkOrderID]", "tbl_WOSamples", "[WOSampleNum] =" & pep & " And [WorkOrderID] =" & ton)

If Forms![Frm_main_WOSamples].[Frm_sub_Qry_stats_WOSamples].Form![CountOfWOSampleNum] = WOSampleNum Then

ElseIf Forms![Frm_main_WOSamples].[Frm_sub_Qry_stats_WOSamples].Form![CountOfWOSampleNum] <> WOSampleNum 
Then

If zar = ton Then

Me.Filter = "WOSampleNum = " & rep
Me.FilterOn = True

ElseIf oar = ton Then

Me.Filter = "WOSampleNum = " & tep
Me.FilterOn = True

ElseIf twar = ton Then

Me.Filter = "WOSampleNum = " & cep
Me.FilterOn = True

ElseIf iar = ton Then

Me.Filter = "WOSampleNum = " & oep
Me.FilterOn = True

ElseIf qar = ton Then

Me.Filter = "WOSampleNum = " & pep
Me.FilterOn = True

End If

End If
```

Comment: I guess that step 1 could be to use an Array and `ReDim` instead of 5 individually named variables?  Also, `Dim rep, tep, cep, oep, pep As String` only makes `pep` a `String` - the rest will be defaulting to `Variant`.  Try `Dim rep As String, tep As String, cep As String, oep As String, pep As String` instead for that.  Or, as suggested earlier `Dim rep(1 to 5) as String`

Comment: If `WorkOrderID` and `WOSampleNum` are both numeric datatypes (it looks like that they are), then all of the variables (`zar`/`oar`/`twar`/`iar`/`qar` and `rep`/`cep`/`oep`/`tep`/`pep`) should all be declared as numeric, probably `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this correctly interprets the logic:

```
Dim ton As Long, won As Long, i As Integer

ton = Me.WorkOrderID

If Forms![Frm_main_WOSamples].[Frm_sub_Qry_stats_WOSamples].Form![CountOfWOSampleNum] <> Me.WOSampleNum Then
    For i = 1 To 5
        won = Me.WOSampleNum + i
        If Nz(DLookup("[WorkOrderID]", "tbl_WOSamples", "[WOSampleNum] =" & won & " And [WorkOrderID] =" & ton), 0) = ton Then
            Me.Filter = "WOSampleNum = " & won
            Me.FilterOn = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```